# Yosemite displaying the blue and grey screen of death

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, macos, startup

I have a late model 2011 MacBook Pro, and I upgraded to Yosemite two weeks ago. Yesterday I was working in After Effects on some pretty big movie files when the laptop screen just went black.

Now when I restart it, the apple comes up, then the thermometer shows for about a third of the way and then the mother blue and grey screen of death.

- I have reset the PRAM
- Tried starting in safe mode, same thing happens
- Tried starting with <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, same thing happens
- Tried starting with <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>opt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> got the terminal spewing out a bunch of tech stuff then went to the the blue grey screen.
- Tried fsck, indicated nothing wrong.
- Tried resetting the NVRAM, would not work, also went to the blue and grey screen.
- Tried starting with <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and emptied trash through the terminal.
- Tried rebuilding permissions in terminal, but was unable to as I was signed in as a single user.

At one point, I held down the "D" key for a long time after it had begun to boot and was asked if I wanted to resume where I left off before the crash, and the system came back online, I said yes. Then started quitting programs and then it went black again, and I have tried to replicate all of this again and again.

I don't understand how I can fix this with the Internet back up when I can't get it to start. It's like looking up a word in the dictionary to find it's meaning only to have them use the word to describe the word.

It looks like the Mac guys have finally figured out how to turn a Mac into a PC using Yosemite.

Comment: 1st step - Cmd/R for Recovery

Comment: Can you access the console.app and post the last entries? I had a somewhat similar situation a while ago - it was a hardware error (grapic memory had overheated), the mainboard had to be replaced.

Comment: I'm unsure how to acces the "console.app", or what that is.

Comment: Cmd/R just gets me to the blue grey screen.

Comment: I have tried ALL of the fixes recommended to the other people here with this challenge. BUT, I am unable to repair my disk permissions in terminal because I'm logged in as single user. And can't figure out how to log in as admin. I don't want to change my admin password,Mahican was the only workaround I could find on net. Do you think this would help? Do you know how to do this?

Comment: this morning after my laptop was shut down for around 20 hours I started by holding down the command/option/R keys and for the first time the "internet recovery is working! @JC did you replace the logic board yourself?

Comment: @J.C. - After trying everything I could on my *own, I set up an appointment with a Genius. He spent about an hour with me trying everything I had tried and a few things I couldn't have. At the end, he said he didn't believe it was hardware, but to leave it for the man behind the curtain. I got a call the next day, saying my logic board was fried. $310.00 to replace it.My work order shows they replaced the Logic Board 2.0 GHz & the symptom was "Video Distortion". SO the Politically Correct term for "The Grey Screen O Death" is "Video Distortion" *YouTube- Bake an Apple_ has shown to work!

Comment: Thanks for the update. Did he try the 'Apple Service Diagnostic'-Tools? It's a Collection of Software Tools (not available for the public) which should have reported the faulty logic board.

Comment: yes, he used several tools I had never seen, and tried to boot from another hard drive with several different OS versions on it. But all his tests and mine showed the hardware was good. He even attempted to start it by disconnecting my hard drive and booting to an alternate.

Comment: Do know approximately what temperature your computer was running at when it crashed originally? It sounds to me like there is a good chance it overheated and fried one of the connections somewhere.